# issues while using @RunWith Annotation and powerMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Initially I was using only Mockito in junits so I was using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class in @RunWith annotation ie

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

due to which spring dependency injection was working fine and was getting a bean through

```
@Autowired

Someservice someservice ;
```

But now, I have also integrated PowerMock in it.

So as per [doc](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) , I have replaced class mentioned in @RunWith annotation with

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

but now, someservice is coming out to be null. Is there a way to use both **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class** and **PowerMockRunner.class** in @RunWith annotation

Answer (score 17):

I know this thread is old, but it's good to add that since 2014 and this [pull request](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/pull/6), you can use the `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` annotation to "delegate" the run context to `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (or any other runner really).

Above code would look like :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(X.class);
public class MyTest {

    // Tests goes here
    ...
}
```

With this annotation, you don't need the PowerMock rule anymore !

Answer (score 16):

You have to use the [PowerMockRule](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(X.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    // Tests goes here
    ...
}
```

For a full example of the Spring Integration Test with PowerMock and Mockito, you could checkout this [maven project](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/tags/powermock-1.4.12/examples/spring-mockito/).

```
svn co http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/tags/powermock-1.4.12/examples/spring-mockito/
cd spring-mockito/
```

Look at the dependecies to powermock.

```
less pom.xml
```

and then run the test

```
mvn test
```

and you should get the following test results :

```
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Hey gontard, I have tried your solution but when I was executing my junit I was getting an exception that PowerMockRule "rule" should be public so I made it public and now I am getting the javassist.NotFoundException. Any thoughts? exeption java.lang.RuntimeException: javassist.NotFoundException: $Proxy88
 at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:187)
 at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:147) ....

Comment: @bhuvan i don't know, perhaps it is [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=350). I complete my answer too.

Comment: @gontard http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/tags/powermock-1.4.12/examples/spring-mockito/ -- this link is no longer working.