# mock static without @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have folowing code:

```
        @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
        @PrepareForTest({RequestUtils.class, OsgiUtil.class})
        @PowerMockIgnore({"*"})
        public class MyTest
            ...
             @Test
             public somMethod(){    
                ....  
                mockStatic(RequestUtils.class);
                when(RequestUtils.getLocale(request)).thenReturn(locale);
            }
        }
```

How to replace this code so that it work without `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

According the cause described in following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454473/junit-parameterized-tests-together-with-powermock-how) I cannot use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Comment: If you cannot use `@RunWith` you do not need annotations. Do you want to create mocks using annotation but without using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

Comment: @AlexR can you provide code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this discussion: [issues while using @RunWith Annotation and powerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158779/issues-while-using-runwith-annotation-and-powermock)

One of the answers recommends to use `PowerMockRule` instead of runner. This solution should be good for you.

Comment: I don't understand hpe to mock static using PowerMockRule

Comment: Rule is not instead of `mockStatic`. It is instead of using runner. To mock static just call method `mockStatic` exactly as you do. This method is implemented in at least 2 classes: one for EasyMock, other for Mockito.

Comment: where should I write rule? How should I use it in my code?

Comment: Please follow the link I provided into my answer. There is an example here. Look for answer given by @gontard.

Comment: I made it but I really don't understand